# mxGraph svg icons set for network diagram images

Tags: svg, icons, mxgraph, gojs, draw.io

We are trying to build an application (to draw Network diagram) like Draw.io. I am looking for icons that they (draw.io) have in the left panel.

I knew draw.io has been built using mxGraph as a base and mxGraph is now a archived repo.

Is there anyway to get the icons list alone from mxGraph?

I am fine with paid icon as well, But where i didn't get the whole list like in the Draw.io.

Any direction on this greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco has released some of their icons for free use:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/brand-center/network-topology-icons.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this should suffice my need.